# Trying to acquire Tizen TV Web App permission

Tags: web, tizen, television

I'm trying to build a POC Voice recognition app on the Tizen TV platform, but using Web application API I've failed at getting the permission for voice control. 
Debug console prints: Cannot read property 'requestPermission' of undefined (in my case the global tizen object has no ppm property which in all examples on the Web should hold the requestPermission method).

```
function requestPermit(uri) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        tizen.ppm.requestPermission(uri,
          function(success) { resolve(success); },
          function(error) { reject(error); });
      });
    }

var start = function() {
    return requestPermit('http://tizen.org/privilege/voicecontrol.tts')
        .then(function() { return init(); })
        .catch(function(err) { return console.log(err); });
}

$(document).bind( 'pageinit', start );
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Privacy Privilege module of Web API is not supported on TV profile. There is no module Privacy Privilege on TV's docs [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/index.html#Security), so the behaviour you met is what I would expect - tizen.ppm is undefined.

Also basing on information [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/tutorials/sec-privileges/):

> Since Tizen 4.0, the status of privacy-related privileges can be resolved at runtime using the Privacy Privilege API (**in mobile and wearable applications**).

There is no need to request a privilege on TV profile.

If you want to check in your code automatically, if the Privacy Privilege module is supported try:

```
if (tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("http://tizen.org/feature/security.privacy_privilege")) {
  // ppm module is supported - you need to request privilege from the user here
} else {
  // ppm module is not supported - just log or ignore, no consent from the user is needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears up that part, however I only tried acquiring permissions after I got WebAPIException code: 18, with message "Permission denied" at VoiceControlClientManager.getVoiceControlClient() which I call at $(document).bind( 'pageinit', init );

Comment: Did you add a 'http://tizen.org/privilege/recorder' privilege to your config.xml file as described here https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/mobile/tizen/voicecontrol.html#VoiceControlClientManager::getVoiceControlClient?

'http://tizen.org/privilege/voicecontrol.tts' is only native/dotnet privilege for tts, but web requires 'recorder' privilege.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason the ppm property of tizen object is undefined.

Comment: tizen.ppm is only mobile and wearable feature - just do not use it on TV.